# Php display image from url into homepage

Tags: php, image, url

after no one answered at this question     [Php Rss feed use img in CDATA -> content:encoded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31771729/php-rss-feed-use-img-in-cdata-contentencoded) i try to do something else solving this problem...

how can i load an image from a given url directly into my homepage?

```
<?php
     $url = "...";
     $image = file_get_contents("$url");
     echo $image;
?>
```

*i don't want to save the image anywhere... just load the image from the url and show it in my own homepage.

Comment: Try this `$image = file_get_contents($url);` or if you are just displaying why dont you just show image from the url

Comment: Now it shows me a lot of letters and question marks... it seem like it tries to decoding the image

Comment: You have to base 64 encode it. Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21600709/4407926

Comment: tried it... it works but show me this -> mime_content_type(): Can only process string or stream arguments

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this code,work fine on my machine.

```
<?php

$image = 'http://www.google.com/doodle4google/images/d4g_logo_global.jpg';
$imageData = base64_encode(file_get_contents($image));
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.$imageData.'">';
?>
```

Comment: Remember to swap image/jpeg with image/png if you are displaying png file.

Comment: This is very slow. Is there any other way to do it perhaps faster

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there. When you download the contents of the file you need to encode it to base64 if you do not plan to store it on server.

```
<?php

$url = '...';
$image = base64_encode(file_get_contents($url));

?>
```

Then you can display it:

```
<img src="data:image/x-icon;base64,<?= $image ?>">
```

Comment: show me this -> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<'

Comment: Can you post your full example somewhere?